# Does increasing RAM help to prevent OOM?

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory

OOM happens when the heap gets full. But what if we increased the size of the RAM of the device, will that help prevent OOM?

I tried to look at tutorials on how to prevent OOM , which recommended multi-threading and trimming down the size of the bitmap. But I still get OOM errors.

Comment: how do you plan to increase the RAM size?

Comment: You have to post your code for us to see how we can optimize this.

Comment: i am doing a createBitmap on a high resolution image, 6000 X6000 and it is causing it to crash

Comment: @FredShmed have you calculated how much memory is needed to create such a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

> But what if we increased the size of the RAM on the device, will that help prevent OOM?

Yes and no. The answer is "it depends on why you are running out of memory."

If you are trying to manipulate a 2GB Bitmap on a 1GB device, then yes, adding a few extra GB of RAM will solve your problem.

If you have a rogue operation that is constantly allocating new Objects, then adding additional memory will just delay the OOM Exception. Extra RAM is not a long term solution to poor memory management.

You need to work to identify why you are running out of memory first. If the issue is that you really do need more RAM (which is fairly unlikely), then go ahead and add more. If the problem is that you are unnecessarily allocating memory or leaking objects, then fix those problems first.

With Bitmaps specifically, you often don't need the full quality image. If your image is stored at 1080p resolution but the device is only a 480p screen, then loading the entire image into memory is a waste of space since most of the image won't be used anyway.

Comment: i am doing a createBitmap on a high resolution image, 6000 X6000 and it is causing it to crash

Comment: Uh, yeah, I would expect that to run out of memory on many devices. Why on earth do you need a 6k Bitmap?

Comment: @Tanis.7x My understanding of the [Managing Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory) guide is that the maximum heap available to an app (returned by `ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()`) is always only a small portion of the total device RAM, often 96MB or less.   Your bitmap scenario is somewhat misleading in that it suggests that an app has access to a very large portion of total device RAM. RAM added to a device (if that were possible) wouldn't benefit any single app, although it would allow more apps to remain in memory for smooth multitasking.

Comment: As that document explains (and as you pointed out), the heap size per-app is a portion of the total memory. Let's assume the portion is 10% for explanation sake- going from 1GB of RAM to 2GB of RAM will give each app an extra ~100MB to work with. Of course in practice the "portion" isn't that high, but it will indeed vary depending on how much memory the device has.